# hardcode pointer value

Tags: c, pointers, spaces

```
char buf[50];
char *ptr = buf;
```

How can I hardcode a space (' ') into a specific pointer locations if I want to hardcode (' ') in 4th, 8th and 16th pointer location?

Comment: What do you mean by 'hardcode'?

Comment: After you do that, be sure to triple check all string functions dealing with `buf` or `ptr`. Depending on what got overwritten, the data may no longer be a string (if it ever was to start with)

Answer (score 3):

```
*(ptr+3) = ' ';
*(ptr+7) = ' ';
*(ptr+15) = ' ';
```

Comment: this is more like 'code' than 'hardcode' because can be rewrited, but probably OP has problem with C++ language then i think is ok

Comment: It should be `*(ptr + 3)`, `*(ptr + 7)` and `*(ptr + 15)`.

Comment: Or `ptr[4] = ' ';` which I think looks more conventional.

Comment: @John Zwinck - Or rather `ptr[3]` which is what I think you meant.

Comment: I just based it off Till's unedited answer.  Till and I might have assumed the OP meant the [4] position when he said fourth, because some C programmers refer to the beginning of an array as the "zeroth" element (C arrays being zero-based).  Anyway, I don't care which number you put in there, I was just advocating for brackets.

Comment: @John and Loki - we just don't know exactly what he means but my initial assumption quickly seemed unlikely to me, hence I corrected it immediately after sending the answer (and shortly before Loki noted it ).

Comment: Strcpy(pSrc, '  '); WILL THIS WORK TOO?!

Comment: @kiran: that won't even compile.  Maybe you meant `strcpy(pSrc, " ")`, which would compile but would make pSrc be a single space followed by a single null.  If you want it to be all spaces, try `memset(buf, ' ', 50);`

Comment: @John I do not want to set all the buf value to space instead for example if I have copied values to buf from 0 to 20 the remaining I want to fill with " " spaces. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: @kiran to fill e.g. index 21-49 with spaces, you could do a `memset(ptr+21, ' ', 29);`

Comment: @John if I am unaware of the remaining empty location in the buffer to fill it with space can I move the pointer to the starting of empty location and do memset(ptr, ' ', sizeof(buf)); Thank you

Comment: @John One more doubt if I locate the pointer to a location and do strcpy(ptr, " "); will it fill all the remaining pointer location with " " or will it fill only the current location?

Comment: strcpy with " " as the source string will just write a space and a null.  Nothing more.  memset with a pointer not pointing to the beginning of the buffer but using the full sizeof(buf) is dangerous, and will cause a buffer overflow (crashing your program, causing a security breach, or worse, doing neither until some future time when one or both happen).

Answer (score 3):

If by hardcoding you mean that you want the value **before** starting any execution (as oposed to Till's answer), you could do something like:

```
char buf[50] = "... ... ....... ";
```

and then the rest of your code. (Note that positions that are not spaces have a value that is irrelevant.